# Telepresence Commands Pop Up an Ambassador Cloud Login Window

Tags: ambassador, telepresence

For some reason, when I run some Telepresence commands, I get a browser window popping up prompting me to log in to Ambassador Cloud.  But I'm not using Ambassador Cloud.

In addition to the browser window, the command shows a message to this effect.  Like this:

```
~ % telepresence intercept my-k8s-service
Launching browser authentication flow...
```

How do I disable this?

Comment: This started with version 2.6, didn't happen in previous versions. I also haven't been able to figure it out, and am going to open an issue about it on the project GitHub if there's not already one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just figured this out -- there are some advanced options you can set by creating a config.yml file for telepresence. Its expected location varies by OS, see the chart here for all supported locations per OS: https://www.getambassador.io/docs/telepresence/latest/reference/config/

The setting we want, which I just tried and worked to disable opening the browser window, is:

```html
cloud:
  skipLogin: true
```

I am on a Mac, and these are the steps I took to fix the issue:

1. Create the file `~/Library/Application\ Support/telepresence/config.yml` and put the above two lines in it. Note that the line break and spaces matter in yaml files like this.
2. `telepresence quit -ur` (which still popped open the browser window one last time)
3. `telepresence connect` -- no longer pops open the browser window, as it now picks up the config setting to skipLogin to their cloud.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone ever suffers from this problem in the future and the `config` solution does not work for them, this solution worked for us:
https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence/issues/2667#issuecomment-1176330566